# jQuery global variable and AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax

i have jQuery code below..

```
(function( $ ) {

$.fn.pokerClass = function( test ) {
    var test;

    this.a = function(){
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "http://127.0.0.1/test.php",
                        success: function(data){
                            var json = $.parseJSON(data);
                            test = json.value; 
                            }
                    });
    }
    this.b = function() {
        alert("i am " + test);
    };
    this.class_var = test;
    return this;
};


})( jQuery );
```

HTML:

```
var t = $(document.body).testClass();
t.a();
t.b();
```

I get response "i am undefined". Can anyone help me how to solve this problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an AJAX call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Answer (score 4):

Your ajax call runs asyncronically so when `t.b();` is executed, `test` has no value yet.

You could execute the ajax call syncronically (`async:false`) or run `t.b();` inside `success` callback

Answer (score 3):

You are using the **async** from of ajax which means that the system won't wait for ajax to finish in order to proceed with the rest.

Just use

```
$.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        async:false, /* Note this */
                        url: "http://127.0.0.1/test.php",
                        success: function(data){
                            var json = $.parseJSON(data);
                            test = json.value; 
                            }
                    });
```

Answer (score 0):

- I think you mean to call `pokerClass`, not `testClass`?
- You get a warning that `test`is already defined. It is the function's argument and you declare it again with `var test;`. You can remove the function argument as you do not pass anything to the function.
- In order to **get** JSON data, you make a `POST` request without sending anything. Consider using the [getJSON function](http://jqapi.com/#p=jQuery.getJSON) instead, although you cannot set the async setting using that shorthand function. You can also set the `dataType` of the expected response to `json`. It is parsed automatically then.
- As Claudio Redi said (first): set the ajax call to `async:false`. You might want to look into the somewhat advanced [`.when()`](http://jqapi.com/#p=jQuery.when) function to wait for the response of an async request.

Not tested:

```
(function( $ ) {
  $.fn.pokerClass = function( ) {
    var test;

    this.a = function(){
      $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        async: false,
        dataType: "json",
        url: "http://127.0.0.1/test.php",
        success: function(data){
          test = data.value;
        },
        error: function(){
          console.log("Did not work.");
        }
      });
    };
    this.b = function() {
      console.log("I am " + test);
    };
    this.class_var = test;
    return this;
  };
})( jQuery );

var t = $("document.body").pokerClass();
t.a();
t.b();
```